# [Github Actions]: "EACCES: permission denied, open " for `vite.config` in hosted image run

Tags: github-actions, vite, nrwl-nx

I have a build using `vite`.

When I'm running build locally and on regular self hosted runners, the build works.

When the build is running on a hosted image based runner, the build fails because it doesn't have permission to access `vite.config` for some reason.

Here's the run:
https://github.com/Vonage/vivid-3/actions/runs/5877034909/job/15939569642

Trying to add `--user root` does not help.

Anyone have any clue what might cause this?

Comment: Possible to remove the `actions/cache@v3` step and see whether that resolves it? Just to confirm whether when cache is used, whether the files are created with permissions not available during this step.

Comment: Thanks for the response @RobinThomas
I tried it without the `cache` and it gives the same error. 
The `cache` was used for `node_modules` only.
Actually, when I created the cache for the `dist` folder and did everything without the build everything worked.
I think it has something to do with the `vite` build and how it transpiles and opens the tmp config file after transpilation.

Comment: Does your cache key hashes `vite.config.*` as well?

Comment: Beforehand, when I cached only `node_modules`, only the lock file was cached.
Now when I cache `dist` it hashes the whole libs folder (including the config file).

Comment: Need to test a hacky solution. Can you add `vite.config.ts.timestamp-*.mjs` to your `.gitignore` and retrigger the github action workflow?

Comment: It doesn't help either :)

Comment: Issue is vite is creating this temp file from `vite.config.ts` which might be auto-deleted or cannot access. If you use `vite.config.js`, no need of this temp file. But that doesn't explain why its happening for `vite.config.ts`

Comment: Can you update your vite version to `4.4.9` (from `4.3.9`) and see if that helps?

Comment: I see this relevant PR: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/12552
But it was merged in 4.3.0...
I'll try, thanks